# Error building an ARM ltsp client image

Tags: server, arm, ltsp, ltsp-client

I have installed ltsp on an Ubuntu 14.04 Server and am trying to build an arm client image using

```
sudo ltsp-build-client --arch armhf
```

The goal is to log into the server using a Raspberry Pi with [Berryterminal](http://www.berryterminal.com/).

But I keep getting the following error:

```
W: Failure trying to run: chroot /opt/ltsp/armhf mount -t proc proc /proc
W: See /opt/ltsp/armhf/debootstrap/debootstrap.log for details
```

debootstrap.log:

```
chroot: failed to run command 'mount': Exec format error
```

Can anyone tell me how I can get get this working? Building the amd64 client work's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://cascadia.debian.net/~vagrant/rpi-ltsp-howto.txt

Install ltsp-server for ltsp-build-client, ldm-server to support LDM, 
qemu-user-static and binfmt-support for cross-architecture support.

```
apt-get install ltsp-server qemu-user-static binfmt-support ldm-server
```